# Joomla 3.8 // New Router & Nested View

Tags: joomla3.8, router

I want to use the new router classes to implement SEF stuff. I still struggle to get it to work.

I have a view which can show categories. So this view is called `categories`. If you click a category, you see the `categories` view again. Despite the name of the view and that there is just one view, this is similar to what `com_content` is doing with the `category` view.

Here is my code for the router constructor:

```
$categories = new JComponentRouterViewconfiguration('categories');
$categories->setKey('catid');
$categories->setNestable();
$this->registerView($categories);
```

That gives me an endless loop if I try to build routes for the categories view.

The class `Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterView\StandardRules` seems to cause the issue here. Since my view has no parent, it can't have children. So the `for (i = 0; i < .....)` in line **237** the `i` variable is counted and down endlessly.

```
else
{
    $i--;
    $found2 = false;
}

if (count($views[$view]->children))
{
    $found = true;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the standard Joomla code supports a single nested view. But how? I'm very thankful for a little hint.

Comment: I'm looking at this and struggling as well! I did come across [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/YnILNx_Lmeg) which may help. You might try copying the getCategorySegment and getCategoryId methods from the com_content code. I think with the old router it was a lot easier to debug your code.

Comment: I created a copy of the original router and modified it so it works for me now. The ID-less routing is fine. But it does not feel right :(

Comment: This might be a bug you know...