# New Router // Nesting, Unique URLs and Multi Parent View Hierarchy

Tags: router

I'm looking for documentation about the new Router arrived in Joomla 3.8/4.0. I already spend some time to figure out how to leverage this new implementation approach to my component and stumbled upon some difficulties.

My main questions are:

1. does the router support nested views without a parent view?
2. how to implement a view with multiple parent views?
3. are the build URLs supposed to avoid duplicated content?
4. is there any good dev documentation about the new Routing System?

For 1. I already filed [Joomla 3.8 // New Router & Nested View](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21954/joomla-3-8-new-router-nested-view)

For 2. I have an item view which can be the child view of a category view or another view. Links to an item don't use the correct ItemId. Maybe this is related to 3.

For 3. I have several menu items which can show the same item. One menu item links to the root category, another to a subcategory. While browsing, I would like to stay within the current menu item. But if I jump from the root menu item to the subcategory, I follow the link to the other menu item.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not have an answer to item 1-3, I can answer my question 4 at least a little bit.

The Joomla documentation was recently updated with information about the new router implementation:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component#The_Component_Router